# Highlighting text via javascript selection on firefox does not put it in X server primary selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

An app I run has blockquoted text which users want to be able to click once to copy to clipboard and paste elsewhere. This mostly works, but when they try to paste using the middle mouse button instead of ctrl+v on linux desktops, firefox won't work. X server has a separate selection buffer called PRIMARY which stores highlighted text to be pasted with the middle button. When you click on the text in chrome, it gets added to PRIMARY, but not in firefox. Manually selecting the text works, however. No problems ctrl+v'ing. 
Any idea why this is happening? Any way to get the text into the PRIMARY selection?

We're running bootstrap 4 if that matters

```
<blockquote id="testblock" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click to copy text">
  <p>Test me</p>
</blockquote>


$('#testblock')
  .attr('data-toggle', 'tooltip')
  .attr('title', 'Click to copy text')
  .click(function() {
    selectElementText($(this)[0]);
    try {
      document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });

function selectElementText(el, win) {
    win = win || window;
    var doc = win.document;
    var sel = win.getSelection();
    var range = doc.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    console.log(sel);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alex2iou/12tLf87s/11/